# How end-user know whether the page is developed using semantic elements in HTML5?

Tags: html

How end-user know whether the page is developed using semantic elements in 
HTML5? What differences end-user can get if we use HTML5 semantic tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is a very valid question and I don't get those haters who downvoted it.

Here is a quick reminder:

**non-semantic elements**: for example div and span - They tell nothing about their content.

**semantic elements**: for example form, table, and img - They clearly defines their content.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp

For your common user it doesn't change anything he will just see how it is displayed (the graphical result).But:

- For you and the people that will work on your code it will be much better if you have a well-organized code with semantic elements used correctly.
- **ACCESSIBILITY** : Blind people and other people with some handicaps or diseases can't see and understand the page with its display. They have special navigators that read them the page with a quick summary based on your h[1-6] elements ( very basic example its far more elaborated actually ).

Read http://www.clarissapeterson.com/2012/11/html5-accessibility/ for more in-depth explanations on that matter.

Comment: Thanks shrimpdrake.

Comment: I also heard that semantic tags will help in searchability,SEO(Search Engine Optimization) and accessibility.